# Why not all timelike world lines have infinite total length?

Tags: general-relativity, singularities

I don't understand this stament by [Geroch(1968)](http://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/%7Egiulini/papers/Geroch_Singularity_AnnPhys1968.pdf), when discussing the definition of singularity:

> We could not have required that all timelike world lines have infinite total length,
> for this property does not obtain in any spacetime.

Can someone give an example of this?
I can only think that in a torus, timelike curves could be closed and thus have finite total length, but this doesn't seems to be a good physical example.

Comment: Why is the torus not a "good" example? (Just because our universe doesn't seem to be a torus so far that doesn't mean the theory forbids such spacetimes) More generically, this phenomenon will occur in *any* compact spacetime.

Comment: @ACuriousMind So does the the statement hold only in compact spaces? I was thinking that the author had in mind some non-compact spacetime with a complicated metric that made timelike curves have finite lenght.

Comment: It beats me. If you consider Minkowski spacetime there are no worldlines that are everywhere timelike and have a finite proper length, and this seems to contradict Geroch.

Comment: @JohnRennie:  I think we can safely assume that Geroch meant NOT(this property obtains in all spacetimes), as opposed to NOT(there exists a spacetime with this property).  I agree that he could have chosen less ambiguous wording.

Comment: @WillO: ah yes. The statement might be less ambiguously expressed as *for this property does not obtain in every possible spacetime*.

Comment: We can construct such a spacetime using some topology. See [this figure from Hawking-Ellis.](https://i.gyazo.com/fcc923039f7202462fa38d1220631be4.png) A timelike curve going between the two right "cut out" strips has finite length and cannot be continuously deformed to give one with infinite length.

Comment: What is not clear in the question? I'm asking for an example.

Comment: @jinawee See my comment from two days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Timelike curves of finite lengths are usually obtained by considering either  :

- Singularities, where the curve will begin and end abruptly. Consider for instance a spacetime with two points removed such that the second point removed is in the chronological future of the first point removed. There will be a curve with no endpoints converging to those two singular points at both ends.
- Closed timelike curves, where the curve will just join up with itself after a while. To take a non-compact example, take the van Stockum metric, 
  \begin{equation}
  ds^2 = -F(r) dt^2 + 2M(r) d\varphi dt + L(r) d\varphi^2 + H(r) (dz^2 + dr^2)
  \end{equation}

Which is a correct metric if the determinant $-(FL+M^2)H^2$ is negative, or $FL + M^2 > 0$.

It is pretty easy to see that, if $L < 0$, the integral curve of $\varphi$, which is a closed curve, will be timelike.

Comment: Are those the only possible cases?

Comment: The only ones I can think of with basic GR. Generically speaking timelike curves that aren't closed will be finite if the manifold is timelike incomplete, which is the usual definition of a singularity.